# How to use bash variable correctly in gitconfig with alias

Tags: git, bash, alias, git-config, dotfiles

This is my alias to create branch and set upstream on that branch later on:

```
create = !sh -c \"branch=$(git branch | peco) 
          && git fetch origin ${branch}:${1} 
          && git checkout $1 
          && git branch -u origin/$(git current) fix/$1\"
```

But no matter I execute the follow command, it keeps showing syntax error, like this: `new-branch-name: develop: command not found`

What do I need to do to make the above alias works? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is not such a command name `current` in git..

#### Here is your fix:

```
create = !sh -c \"branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && git fetch origin ${branch}:${1} && git checkout $1 && git branch -u origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) fix/$1\"
```

---

#### On Multiple lines for easy reading:

```
create = !sh -c \"branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) 
         && git fetch origin ${branch}:${1} 
         && git checkout $1 
         && git branch -u origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) fix/$1\"
```

Comment: 1. I have an alias called current: `current = rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD` \n 2. the multiple lines will raise syntax error \n 3. The command result is same: `git create amend/new-branch` will give `amend/new-branch: <upstream nane>: command not found` \n